# Reference a variable in the s:url action attribute

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

So I have a variable set in the page scope like:

```
<s:set name="targetAction" var="targetAction" value="%{'someActionName'}" />
```

I want to use this "targetAction" variable in the action attribute of the `<s:url>` tag. Is this possible?
I tried this way:

```
<s:url action="%{#targetAction}" />
```

but the action attribute is not evaluated and it is set to `"%{#targetAction}"` instead of the value specified in `<s:set>` tag by `someActionName` variable.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Corrected the typo with double quotes.

EDIT2:
Well, I'm using struts 2.1.3 if that matters at all. Anyway, I intend to use this url in a javascript variable like this:

```
var targetAction = '<s:property value="%{#targetAction}" />';
var actionURL = '<s:url action="<my dynamic action name specified by the targetAction variable needs to be here>" />
```

Is there anyway to let it know that value mentioned for the action attribute is a javascript variable and not a string as such? I mean how do I escape javascript content in this scenario?

Comment: Don't use both `name` and `var`, I don't really know what could happen. Use `var` because `name` is for `Struts 2.0`

Comment: I've been using name and var throughout my application, and it works without any issue. Anyway, I've corrected that and the issue's still there :(

Comment: I hope you are not concatenating `targetAction` var in `actionURL` var, like `actionURL = '<s:url action='+targetAction+'/>';` , right?

Comment: I'm not. But I just had to get the desired action name in the `action` attribute of `url` tag. Since I can't declare a tag within another tag, I chose to have a js variable for that (`targetAction`) and make use if that in the `url` tag, which I didn't know how to.

Comment: You can't mix JS variables and Struts Tags. Struts Tags are evaluated serverside, JS variables clientside. @AleksandrM code works, in 2.3 as in 2.1 I guess. Copy and paste literally please, and avoid javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. The `name` attribute of `<s:set>` tag is deprecated use `var` instead.

BTW this variable a not set in page scope because you are not using `scope="page"` and default is action scope.

And you have typo in `action` attribute.

```
<s:set var="targetAction" value="%{'someActionName'}" />
<s:url action="%{#targetAction}" />
```

Javascript:

```
var targetAction = '<s:property value="%{#targetAction}" />';
var actionURL = '<s:url action="%{#targetAction}" />';
```

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I had it correctly on my code, but still <s:url action="%{#targetAction}" /> evaluates to %{#targetAction} for me! Does the struts version matter? I use 2.1.3

Comment: Well totally unlikely :( but isn't this supported in struts 2.1.3? Anyway, I've updated the question with a few more info about what I'm looking for.

Comment: I checked the page source for the generated URL and it has the encoded form of %{#targetAction} specified for the action, not the actual target action name that I wanted.

Comment: Your javascript should be placed after Struts2 tags.

Comment: Hmm for the same reason it didn't work for me before, the Javscript in your answer doesn't work as expected either- the `targetAction` evaluates to my desired action name but my `actionURL` doesn't.

Comment: @mystarrocks: If your `targetAction` assigns correctly then `actionURL` should be also assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably don't use `alTSyntax` in the tags. Try to set it to `true` in `struts.properties`.

```
### use alternative syntax that requires %{} in most places
### to evaluate expressions for String attributes for tags
struts.tag.altSyntax=true
```

Comment: `altSyntax` *forces* the use of `%{}` for evaluation; it shouldn't have an impact if they're already using it. Plus it's true by default.

Comment: It does, that is the question, if you have an answer post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Struts 2.3 worked

```
            <c:set var="businessActionMapping" value="foo" scope="session"/>
            <s:form action="%{#session.businessActionMapping}"
```

You might have need to set altSyntax=TRUE in struts.properties